# wamp is not going green after php version is upgraded

Tags: php, wamp

I update the Wamp server, PHP 5.3.13 to 5.6.2 version and after that switch into new php version and Wamp server not working for new PHP version when I switch version and use Wamp server getting the message that unable to connect 
But when i switch to old one no problem with working Wamp server i dont know what is the problem with the new one please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you had PHP 5.3.13 running it was with an Apache 2.2 version, both compiled with VC6.

The PHP 5.6.2 will have been compiled with VC11 so you also need to upgrade Apache to a version compiled with VC11. So that means an Apache 2.4.4 or above. Basically you may as well go for the latest Apache version.